# React Input onChange before onKeyDown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const {useMemo, useState, createRef} = React;
const InputPIN = (props) => {
  const inputRefs = useMemo(() => Array(4).fill(0).map(i=> createRef()), []);
  const [values, setValues] = useState(Array(4).fill(''));
  function handleChange(e, index){
    const typed = e.target.value.toString();
    setValues((prev)=>
      prev.map((i,jndex) => {
        if(index === jndex) return typed[typed.length-1];
        else return i;
      })
    );
    if (typed !=='' &&  inputRefs[index + 1]) inputRefs[index + 1].current.focus();
  }
  function handleBackspace(e, index) {
    if(e.keyCode === 8){
      if(inputRefs[index-1]){
        inputRefs[index - 1].current.focus();
      }
    }
  }
  return (
    <label className="InputPIN">
      {
        new Array(4).fill(0).map((i,index)=>(
        <input style={{width:50}} key={index} value={values[index]} onKeyDown={(e)=>handleBackspace(e,index)} type="text" ref={inputRefs[index]} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e,index)} /> ) )
      }
    </label>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <InputPIN />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

I am making an `InputPIN` component.

When I typed a text, input focusing would be moved to the next input.

and When I typed the **backspace**, input focusing would be moved to the previous input after removing a present text. But It doesn't work.

on my code, I am using `onKeyDown()` and `onChange()`.
and I guess `onKeyDown()` has a higher priority than `onChange()`.

so, I've tried to change `onKeyDown()` to `onKeyUp()`. 
but it has a side effect that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The whole answer has been updated after the discussion in comments.

I think you can just use a custom handler function, and rewrite a little the two handlers methods:

```
const manualUpdateInputs = (index) => {    
    const newValues = [...values];

    newValues[index] = '';
    inputRefs[index].current.focus();    
}

const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const newValues = [...values];
    const typed = e.target.value.toString();

    newValues[index] = typed;

    if (typed !=='' &&  inputRefs[index + 1]) {
       inputRefs[index + 1].current.focus();
    }

    setValues(newValues);
}

const handleBackspace = (e, index) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 8){
        if(inputRefs[index-1] && e.target.value === '') {
            manualUpdateInputs(index - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the way you update `values` but you can keep your way, it doesn't change. What matters is the use of `manualUpdateInputs`.

The "trick" was that `handleBackspace` is triggered anytime you click a key in the keyboard, but `handleChange` was not triggered if you clicked a backspace with an empty `<input>`.

Tell me if the behavior obtained with this implementation is what you wanted (it makes sense to me, but maybe it's not what you wanted).

Comment: `onChange()` doesn't give `e.keyCode`

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry. I will edit my answer finding a solution, but first a question, because by looking at your snippet I'm not sure about what you want.
Imagine I've filled the first `<input>` and now I've focus on the second `<input>`.If I press backspace, should I just change focus on the previous one, or should I also remove the character in the first `<input>`? And then, if I have focus on the second `<input>`, which is already filled, and press backspace, should I remove the value and set the focus on the previous `<input>` or just deleting the value?

Comment: On my snippet, I have 4 inputs, and I can type them. If I finished typing all of the inputs, and I typed `backspace` it doesn't work well.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I've implemented what you wanted by using a ref (I will explain the choice in the answer). Though, the behavior now it's not good: if I fill all the inputs, then backspace, I delete the last input and change the focus on the previous `<input>`, but then I've the focus on an `<input>` that is already filled, and if I enter a digit, it is entered in the already filled `<input>`. I don't know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I've updated the answer, take a look at the new code :)